# Не до конца понимаю Наследование в с++

Tags: c++

Что такое наследование в с++? Вот написал я класс

```
class IODevice
{
private:

public:
IODevice();
int readData(int address_device, int addr, int nb, unsigned short int* tab_reg);
int writeData(int address_device, int addr, int nb, unsigned short int *tab_reg);
int readId(int address_device, int size, unsigned char* text);
};
```

Если я унаследую этот класс в нескольких классах "class_1", "class_2". И "class_2" передам во второй поток, то как будет происходить обращение к методам класса "IODevice"? При наследование, выделяется память и туда копируется объект класса родителя или происходит обращение к одному классу родителю?

Comment: Не понимаю Наследование в с++© (без подтекста) а где понимаете? -- https://metanit.com/cpp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если говорить в общем, то в С++ наследование как матрешка. Все экземпляры класса-потомка имеют в своем составе экземпляр класса-предка. Для экземпляров классов-потомков доступны методы класса-предка (применительно к экземпляру класса-предка, входящего в состав класса-потомка).

Ну и есть разные нюансы, связанные с областью видимости методов и полей-данных. Но это уже подробности.

Answer (score 1):

При создании наследника выделяется память под объект наследника, в который включен объект предка. Он не копируется, он создается в памяти, выделенной наследнику, как часть конструирования наследника.

Comment: а в с++ есть `static`?

Comment: Его даже больше, чем в C. Например, `static`, как и в C, для ограничения области видимости или `static` локальные переменные. Но есть и `static` члены классов, например.

Comment: а статичная переменная будет шариться между наследниками, модулями при импорте .. ?

Comment: @qwabra Мне непонятна терминология вопроса.

Comment: @qwabra, *`"шариться при импорте"`* -- хороший вопрос, если под импортом вы подразумеваете shared libraries (.so/.dll) / Задайте его, мне самому стало интересно, как компилятор обеспечивает ссылки а общий экземпляр статических полей при доступе из классов, размещаемых в дальнейшем в разных shared libs

Comment: @avp я думаю компилятор сотворит магию в таком случае)